# changes in config.txt are not applied

Tags: hdmi, config.txt

I edited the `/boot/config.txt` file to adapt to my monitor settings:

```
# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
hdmi_safe=1
```

and

```
hdmi_mode=58
```

But when I reboot, the hdmi mode seems to be set back to `4` which is 640x480

How do I apply the change?

This is the output of

```
tvservice -d edid.dat
edidparser edid.dat
```

https://gist.github.com/rubo77/5fab1b1d65899bf81787

Answer (score 1):

I checked with an old Raspberry Mate 15.04 installation where the screen worked fine, and found out, that the settings provided in the 15.10 installation image contain some settings in `config.txt` that break the display resolution:

```
framebuffer_depth=32
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

I commented out all settings in `config.txt` (also the newly made ones) and rebooted... everything worked fine with the default settings.

Maybe I could have also just have removed the config.txt file, didn't try that